# Code Contracts in .NET 4.0, no joy for non-nullable reference types fans?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, c#-4.0, code-contracts

I've been playing with Code Contracts on VS2008 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/dd491992.aspx).
They surely are nice and provide a solid alternative to if-then-throw checks inside methods.

Nonetheless I've been hoping that they could satisfy the need that I strongly feel for non-nullable reference types.
Alas, from what I could see this doesn't seem to be the case.
This is what I understood:

- Something like this will still cause issues at runtime:

  `MyClass a = null;

  a.ToString();`
- I still have to explicitly write checks, even if in a more concise and streamlined way.
- Unless you use VS Team System you can only use code contracts to check things at runtime, no benefits at compile time.
  Meaning that you still have to handle things when something goes wrong.
  Not much different from handling a simple exception.
- Even with VSTS static analysis isn't as a good as the one done at runtime.
  This is perfectly understandable, still it's another sign that this feature is meant for runtime usage.

Please correct me if I'm wrong but from what I see there's no way Code Contracts can make my life easier, and my programs more robust, like non-nullable reference types would.

Don't get me wrong, I don't dislike code contracts.
They are a very nice enhancement to the whole framework.
It's just that if this doesn't fill the gap that C# leaves by not having non-nullable reference types, at this point I'm afraid that nothing will.
What do you think?

Comment: Well... there is now (2017) a prototype for playing with *Nullable* reference type. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47339130/6309)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think you're correct about this. Non-nullable reference checking at compile time was the killer feature I was waiting for in Code Contracts, and it isn't really there.

For those wondering what this means, consider an analogy with value types. They were not nullable originally, but now they are if you put a question mark after the type name:

```
int? n;
```

For consistency it would be ideal if the same was true of reference types. But that would break all existing C# programs and so isn't an option. In the research language [Spec#](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/specsharp/) they went with using an exclamation mark suffix to mean non-nullable:

```
string! s = "Hello";
```

As with ordinary value types, the compiler statically checks that a `string!` variable is not used on any code path before it has been initialised (I believe Spec# requires declaration and initialization to occur in the same statement).

It also bans the assignment of `null` to that variable.

And of course, it bans the assignment of an ordinary `string` to a `string!`. So how do bridge the gap between the two kinds of type? By writing a check:

```
string x = GetStringFromSomewhere();

if (x != null)
    s = x; // okay because compiler sees null check
```

The sad truth is that the majority of reference variables in most programs are likely to be non-nullable if the program is correct. Nullable variables are in the minority. And yet they are the default.

[Another bad idea from the 1960s](http://qconlondon.com/london-2009/presentation/Null+References:+The+Billion+Dollar+Mistake)!

Comment: What would `default(string!)` be? What would be the value of a `string!` field in a struct I initialized with the default constructor?

Comment: Those cases simply shouldn't compile - `default(string!)` is a contradiction: "What is the pre-initialization value of the thing that must be initialised before its value can be read?" And perhaps non-nullable fields needn't even be allowed in structs at all. Structs are already crappy.

Comment: One irritating fact is that the CLR has an obscure way to allow objects of a class to be created without running *any* constructor - but if you use that, then all bets are off. This would mean that under some pathological circumstances the value of a `T!` may be `null`.

Comment: @DanielEarwicker: An exposed-field struct encapsulates a group of variables bound together with duct tape. When one needs a group of variables bound together with duct tape, exposed-field structs are an almost perfect fit. Because code which owns a struct type storage location owns all the fields therein, struct types cannot enforce invariants and shouldn't be expected to, but I wouldn't say that makes them "crappy". That fact that it's hard to pound a screw into a piece of wood doesn't mean it should be regarded an inferior nail.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what problem is solved by "non-nullable reference types".  Ok so this code is much less likely to throw an exception:-

```
a.ToString();
```

However is it anymore likely to be **correct** because a it non-nullable?  What would be the initial value of `a`?  Probably some default "Empty" instance of the type.  In that case isn't it more likely to make things more difficult to debug since values which should've been assigned a value haven't.   Just having some default behaviour rather than causing an exception doesn't sound like something I'd want.

Comment: I see your point but I really wouldn't mind having to provide a reference or instantiate a class when declaring a variable.

Comment: Yet in many cases you wouldn't be in a position to provide the variable with a __correct__ reference at the point of declaration, so you'd give it a temporary one.  Then you're back to square one.  Note also that non-nullable would require runtime checks on every assignment to the variable to see if what is being assigned is a null.

Comment: I sure hope no one declares all variables with a value just to "avoid null references". There should be a reason to create a variable and assign a value. If you're not in a position to provide a correct value, then the API/code is quite broken.

Comment: @MichaelGG: I assume since a late downvote co-incided with your comment that it was yours.  Yet your comment is basically inline with what I was saying.  Or do you think having non-nullable types is a good idea (I don't)?  Or do you have some other reason for the downvote, I don't get what your issue is here?

Comment: I don't think you'd be inline variables as "can't be null", but rather specifying method parameters as "can't pass null".  So you would not need generate dummy data when declaring variables.

Comment: Non-nullable references can help improve code.  It can reduce the changes that you set a variable to null and forget to add the method that creates the instance reference.  And it could be checked by the compiler instead of waiting for runtime. (At which point it will puke all over its self.)

Comment: You don't need a check on every assignment to a variable, only when assigning a possibly null value. Strings show this quite clearly. `string! x="initial value"; x=x+" has been changed";` Now, ignoring the fact that the compiler is going to optimize that away, no runtime check is required, the compiler can see that the variable never has the opportunity to be anything but non-null.

Answer (score 3):

I think the concept of a non-nullable reference type would be really useful for ORM generated properties that map to database fields. Often you can't tell from the property (usually type string) whether the underlying field is nullable or not. With nullable value types you can, just by looking for the question mark.

I'm not too worried about static checking, apart from obvious foo! = null; failing, but the intellisense would be very useful as a hint to variable intent, I think.

Answer (score 0):

> Non-nullable reference checking at compile time was the killer feature I was waiting for in Code Contracts, and it isn't really there.

Update 2017 (8 years later), while Non-nullable reference type is still not there... nullable reference type might.

[Mads Torgersen](https://twitter.com/MadsTorgersen) (C# Language PM at Microsoft) does mention it [in this tweet](https://twitter.com/MadsTorgersen/status/930892718254862336):

> The prototype of nullable reference types is finally here!

This is detailed in "[Introducing Nullable Reference Types in C#](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/11/15/nullable-reference-types-in-csharp/)", and in this video "[new features available C# 7.1 and 7.2](https://channel9.msdn.com/events/Connect/2017/T122)".

> This can be achieved if instead we add only one new “safe” kind of reference type, and then reinterpret existing reference types as being the other “safe” kind. More specifically, **we think that the default meaning of unannotated reference types such as string should be non-nullable reference types**, for a couple of reasons:
>
> **We believe that it is more common to want a reference not to be null. Nullable reference types would be the rarer kind** (though we don’t have good data to tell us by how much), so they are the ones that should require a new annotation.
>   The language already has a notion of – and a syntax for – nullable value types. The analogy between the two would make the language addition conceptually easier, and linguistically simpler.
>   It seems right that you shouldn’t burden yourself or your consumer with cumbersome null values unless you’ve actively decided that you want them. Nulls, not the absence of them, should be the thing that you explicitly have to opt in to.
>   Here’s what it looks like:

```
class Person
{
    public string FirstName;   // Not null
    public string? MiddleName; // May be null
    public string LastName;    // Not null
}
```

> This class is now able to express the intent that everyone has a first and a last name, but only some people have a middle name.
>
> Thus we get to the reason we call this language feature “nullable reference types”: Those are the ones that get added to the language. The nonnullable ones are already there, at least syntactically.

This is still a **prototype**, and might end up (or not) in the language.
See more at "[The C# Nullable Reference Types Preview](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/wiki/Nullable-Reference-Types-Preview)".

Answer (score -2):

rather than using null you can use a default like string.empty  there is no need for nulls